# is there any strncpy() equivalent function in python?

Tags: python

is there any equivalent function for strncpy() of C in python?
I want to replace 6 characters in the second string from the first string.
'wonderful' should be replaced with 'beautiful'. The following is the code in C.

```
str1 = "wonderful";
str2 = "beautiful";
strncpy(str2,str1,6);
```

I want to do this in python.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: string in python is immutable.

Answer (score 6):

> I want to replace 6 characters in the second string from the first string

```
str2 = str1[:6] + str2[6:]
```

Comment: -0.  I don't think this answer can be fully accurate without mentioning the immutability of strings.

Answer (score 5):

You don't copy strings in python as they're immutable.  You simply reassign them like this:

```
str2 = str1[:6] + str2[6:]
```

you also have your destination and source strings mixed up.

Answer (score 4):

Python strings are immutable, so you cannot modify them like you do in other languages. You have to create a new string and reassign `str2`:

```
str2 = str1[:6] + str2[6:]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`bytearray`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#bytearray) if you want in-place modification(normal strings are immutable):

```
>>> str1 = bytearray("wonderful")
>>> str2 = bytearray("beautiful")
for i in xrange(6):
    str2[i] = str1[i]
...     
>>> print str2
wonderful
```

Function:

```
def strncpy(a, b, ind1, ind2):
    for i in xrange(ind1-1, ind2):
        a[i] = b[i]
...         
>>> str1 = bytearray("wonderful")
>>> str2 = bytearray("beautiful")
>>> strncpy(str2, str1, 1, 6)
>>> print str2
wonderful
```

Comment: Byte arrays support slicing as well: `str2[:6] = str1[:6]`