# Is there any equivalent function to strnset() of C in Python?

Tags: python, c

How can I perform this in Python?

```
strnset(string,symbol,n);
```

Output should be:

```
Enter String : ABCDEFGHIJ
Enter Symbol for replacement : +
How many string characters to be replaced : 4

Before strnset() : ABCDEFGHIJ
After strnset() : ++++EFGHIJ
```

Comment: Technically you can't, since strings in Python are immutable.

Comment: Seriously? You're asking this even after the responses you got for your [`strncpy` question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18535563/is-there-any-strncpy-equivalent-function-in-python)?

Answer (score 6):

You'll want to use [Python's Slice Notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/the-python-slice-notation):

```
>>> def strnset(mystring, symbol, n):
...     return symbol*n + mystring[n:]
... 
>>> print strnset("ABCDEFGHIJ", "+", 4)
++++EFGHIJ
```

`mystring[n:]` gets every character after the nth character in the string. Then you can simply join it together with the signs.

Note, if you don't want a string returned which has more characters than the string you actually passed (eg, `strnset('hi', '+', 4) == '++++')`, then add this before the `return` statement:

```
n = min(len(mystring), n)
```

Now, when running:

```
>>> print strnset("HAI", "+", 4)
+++
```

Comment: Nice answer! I'd just make `n = min(len(string), n)` to ensure you don't return something bigger than it was.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one with a generator expression:

```
chars = "ABCDEJGHIJ" 
r = "+" 
n = 4 
masked_result = "".join(r if idx <= n else c for idx, c in enumerate(chars, 1))
```

`>>> '++++EJGHIJ'`

**Note:** this supports masking values less than `n`.